# How to find the MLE of these parameters given distribution?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, exponential-distribution, censoring

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent exponential random variables, with

$$f(x\mid\lambda)=\frac{1}{\lambda}\exp{\left(-\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)},\,x>0\,, \qquad f(y\mid\mu)=\frac{1}{\mu}\exp{\left(-\frac{y}{\mu}\right)},\,y>0$$

We observe $Z$ and $W$ with $Z=\min(X,Y)$, and $W=\begin{cases} 1 &,\text{if }Z=X\\ 0 &,\text{if }Z=Y \end{cases}$

I have obtained the joint distribution of $Z$ and $W$, i.e.,
$$P(Z \leq z, W=0)=\frac{\lambda}{\mu+\lambda}\left[1-\exp{\left(-\left(\frac{1}{\mu}+\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)z\right)}\right]$$

$$P(Z \leq z, W=1)=\frac{\mu}{\mu+\lambda}\left[1-\exp{\left(-\left(\frac{1}{\mu}+\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)z\right)}\right]$$

Now assume that $(Z_i,W_i),i=1,\cdots,n$, are $n$ i.i.d observations. Find the MLEs of $\lambda$ and $\mu$.

(This is the exercise 7.14 of the book Statistical Inference 2nd edition, but no solution given)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $Z$ and $W$ are in fact [independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049403/what-is-the-joint-distribution-of-z-minx-y-and-i-z-x?rq=1), with $W\sim \mathsf{Ber}\left(\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}\right)$ and $Z\sim \mathsf{Exp}$ with rate $(\frac1\lambda+\frac1\mu)$. Therefore for ${z>0\,,\,w\in\{0,1\}}$, we can write the likelihood function based on $(z,w)$ as

\begin{align}
L(\lambda,\mu)&=P(W=w)f_Z(z)
\\&=\frac{1}{\lambda^w \mu^{1-w}}\exp\left[-\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}+\frac{1}{\mu}\right)z\right]\quad,\,(\lambda,\mu)\in \mathbb R^+\times\mathbb R^+.
\end{align}

So the likelihood given the sample $(z_1,w_1),\ldots,(z_n,w_n)$ is

$$L^*(\lambda,\mu)=\frac{1}{\lambda^{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}\mu^{n-\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}}\exp\left[-\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}+\frac{1}{\mu}\right)\sum_{i=1}^n z_i\right]$$

Log-likelihood is

$$\ell(\lambda,\mu)=-\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\ln\lambda-\left(n-\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\right)\ln\mu--\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}+\frac{1}{\mu}\right)\sum_{i=1}^n z_i$$

For $0<\bar w<1$, solving for the stationary points of $\ell(\lambda,\mu)$ yields $$\hat\lambda=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n z_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}=\frac{\bar z}{\bar w}\qquad,\qquad \hat\mu=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n z_i}{n-\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}=\frac{\bar z}{1-\bar w}$$

So assuming $0<\bar w<1$, the unique MLE of $(\lambda,\mu)$ is $(\hat\lambda,\hat\mu)$.

But when $\bar w\in\{0,1\}$, the MLE does not exist.

Comment: I still have two questions. (Q1) How to solve for the stationary points of $\ell(\lambda,\mu)$? (Q2) Why do we need to discuss the value range of $\bar{w}$? (In addition) Shouldn't the $\mu$ in your Log-likelihood is $\ln\mu$?

Comment: You are right about the log-likelihood. I will edit.

Comment: @TimXu I just differentiated $\ell$ once wrt $\lambda$ and $\mu$ and set them equal to zero (for multiple parameters, one should ideally check whether the Hessian matrix of the log-likelihood is negative definite at $(\hat\lambda,\hat\mu)$, provided the derivatives exist). And you can see from the expression for $\hat\lambda,\hat\mu$ that they are not defined at $\bar w=0,1$. Hence the range distinction.

Answer (score 0):

The $W=0$ and the $W=1$ case can be combined by writing $\lambda^{1-W}\mu^W$.

First differentiating w.r.t. $z$ and forming the product the likelihood can be written as $\prod_i^n{\frac{1}{\lambda^{w_i}\mu^{1-w_i}}}e^{-(\frac{1}{\lambda}+\frac{1}{\mu})z_i}$.
Taking logs gives the log likelihood $=-\sum_i^n(w_i\ln{\lambda}+(1-w_i)\ln{\mu}+(\frac{1}{\lambda}+\frac{1}{\mu})z_i)$.

Maximising wrt $\lambda$ and $\mu$ gives $\lambda=\frac{\bar{z}}{\bar{w}}$ and $\mu=\frac{\bar{z}}{(1-\bar{w})}$

Note if $\lambda=\mu$ then $\bar{w}\approx\frac{1}{2}$ so the estimates for $\lambda$ and $\mu$  become equal.

Comment: Denote the log likelihood by $\log L$. First differentiating w.r.t. $\lambda$ and $\mu$, gives $\hat{\lambda}=\frac{\bar{z}}{\bar{w}}$, $\hat{\mu}=\frac{\bar{z}}{1-\bar{w}}$. To make sure they are the maximizers of the log likelihood. I calculate their second-order differentials w.r.t. $\lambda$ and $\mu$, and get that $\frac{\partial^2 \log L}{\partial \lambda^2}=-\sum_{i=1}^n(-\frac{w_i}{\lambda^2}+2\frac{z_i}{\lambda^3})$ and $\frac{\partial^2 \log L}{\partial \mu^2}=-\sum_{i=1}^n(-\frac{1-w_i}{\mu^2}+2\frac{z_i}{\mu^3})$. How do you know these two second-order differentials are negative?

Comment: Direct substitution. for instance $\frac{\partial^2 \log{L}}{\partial \lambda^2}=-\frac{\bar{w}^3}{\bar{z}^2}$

Comment: You missed an $n$. It is $\frac{\partial ^2 \log{L}}{\partial \lambda^2} |_{\lambda=\frac{\bar z}{\bar w}}=
-\sum_{i=1}^n (-\frac{w_i}{\lambda^2}+2\frac{z_i}{\lambda^3}) |_{\lambda=\frac{\bar z}{\bar w}}=
(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}{\lambda^2}-2\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n z_i}{\lambda^3}) |_{\lambda=\frac{\bar z}{\bar w}}=
(\frac{n \bar w}{\lambda^2}-2\frac{n \bar z}{\lambda^3}) |_{\lambda=\frac{\bar z}{\bar w}}=
\frac{n \bar w^3}{\bar z^2}-2\frac{n \bar z \bar w^3}{\bar z^3}=
\frac{n \bar w^3}{\bar z^2}-2\frac{n \bar w^3}{\bar z^2}=-\frac{n \bar w^3}{\bar z^2}$