# the joint distribution of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let's say we have two independent exponential random variables A and B with parameters $\mu$ and $\lambda$ such that:

$$f(a|\mu) = \mu e^{-\mu a}  $$
$$f(b|\lambda) = \lambda e^{-\lambda b}$$

Now we don't observe these two variables but instead, observe T and Z with:

$$T = \min(A,B)$$
$$Z =
   \begin{cases}
    1     & \text{if $T = A$}, \\
    0 & \text{if $T = B$}.
  \end{cases} $$

what is the joint distribution of T and Z?

this is how I have approached the problem so far, but I couldn't reach a result and need guidance to see if I am on the right track.

$$ 
\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned} 
F_{T,Z}(t,z) &= P(T \leq t, Z \leq z)\\
&=  P(T \leq t | Z \leq z) P(Z\leq z)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$$

we know that for $ z < 0, F_Z(z) = 0$; for $z \geq 1, F_Z(z) = 1$ and for $0 \leq z < 1,  F_Z(z) = P(B < A)$.

we also know that given $ 0 \leq z < 1, t = B $ and given $z = 1, t = A$.

so I thought I can rewrite $F_{T,Z}(t,z)$ as:

$$F_{T,Z}(t,z)
   \begin{cases}
    0     & \text{if $Z < 0$}, \\
    \lambda e^{-\lambda b} P(\lambda e^{-\lambda b} < \mu e^{-\mu a}) & \text{if $0 \leq Z < 1$}, \\
    \mu e^{-\mu a} & \text{if Z > 1}.
  \end{cases} 
$$

But I can't tell if this is a good approach or how to calculate $P(\lambda e^{-\lambda b} < \mu e^{-\mu a})$ if it is. Can anyone help?

Comment: Previously asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1049403/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marginal of $Z$:

\begin{align}
P(B < A)
&= \iint_{b<a} f_A(a) f_B(b) \, da \, db
\\
&= \int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda b} \int_b^\infty \mu e^{-\mu a} \, da \, db
\\
&= \int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda b} e^{-\mu b} \, db
\\
&= \frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}.
\end{align}

So $P(Z=0)=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}$ and $P(Z=1)=\frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu}$.

---

Marginal of $T$:

\begin{align}
P(T > t)
&= P(A>t) P(B>t)
\\
&= \int_t^\infty \mu e^{-\mu a} \, da \int_t^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda b} \, db
\\
&= e^{-(\lambda + \mu)t}.
\end{align}

---

Joint distribution:

\begin{align}
P(T > t, Z = 0)
&= P(t < B < A)
\\
&= \iint_{t < b < a} f_A(a) f_B(b) \, da \, db
\\
&= \int_t^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda b} \int_b^\infty \mu e^{-\mu a} \, da \, db
\\
&= \int_t^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda b} e^{-\mu b} \, db
\\
&= \frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu} e^{-(\lambda + \mu) t}.
\end{align}

By a similar computation, $P(T>t, Z=1) = \frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu} e^{-(\lambda+\mu)t}$.

---

Sanity checks for the joint distribution:

- $P(T>t, Z=0) + P(T>t, Z=1)$ equals the marginal probability $P(T>t)$ computed earlier.
- When $t=0$, $P(T>t, Z=0)$ equals the marginal probability $P(Z=0)$ computed earlier.

---

If you need to put things in the form $P(T \le t, Z=z)$, note that this equals $P(Z=z) - P(T > t, Z=z)$.