# Ask the independence of $Z=\min(X,Y)$ and $I_{Z=X}$?

Tags: probability, statistics

X and Y are independent random variables with X ~ exponential($\lambda$) and Y ~ exponential($\mu$). It is impossible to obtain direct observations of X and Y. Instead, we observe the random variables Z and W, where Z=min(X,Y) and W=1 if Z=X, W=0 if Z=Y.

I know how to prove that Z and W are independent. The solution can be seen here: [What is the joint distribution of $Z=\min(X,Y)$ and $I_{Z=X}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049403/what-is-the-joint-distribution-of-z-minx-y-and-i-z-x)

**My first question is**: how come they can be independent? It's really counter-intuitive for me. If I know Z=X, then I will immediately know what W is. Intuitively, this means Z and W should be highly dependent.

**My second question is: w**hen I try to prove they are independent, I use the hint from Casella's textbook (the question is chapter 4 exercise 4.26). I need to show $P(Z \leq z | W=0) = P(Z \leq z)$.

To show the above I compute $P(Z \leq z | W=0) = \frac{P(Z \leq z, W=0)}{P(W=0)}$. My question is $P(W=0) = P(Z=Y)=P(Y \leq X)$. My first attempt is that since both X and Y are $\geq 0$. Then the area of first quadrant should be 1 (double integral). Thus, $P(Y \leq X)$ should be 1/2. But my idea turns out to be wrong. I know how to compute it in double integral. But I want to ask why my idea turns out to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**To your first question:** Knowing that $Z=X$ doesn't tell you what the value is of that $X$. And that value is still independent from the knowledge of it being minimal.

**To your second question:** You forget that the quadrants will be weighted differently because $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $Y \sim \text{Exp}(\mu)$, hence leading to a probability of $\mu/(\lambda+\mu)$.